# Glide: Prevent loading images from disk, load from server each time via module

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm using `AppGlideModule` for customize [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/) as my image loader.

How force it to load images from network (url)? (Not from DiskCache)

**Note**: I know this will happen by setting `diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)` for each call like this:

```
GlideApp.with(view)
   .load(imgUrl)
   .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
   .into(binding.imgCover)
```

But I'm looking for apply this configuration for whole application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`diskCacheStrategy` will apply as `RequestOptions`. So I tried this:

```
@GlideModule
class CustomGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun applyOptions(context: Context, builder: GlideBuilder) {
        builder.setDefaultRequestOptions {
            RequestOptions()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a process wide implementation you could choose to configure a no-op custom disk cache during configuration of your module like so:

```
@GlideModule
public class YourAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
        builder.setDiskCache(new DiskCache.Factory() {
            @Override
            public DiskCache build() {
                return new NoOpDiskCache();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For the `NoOpDiskCache` return null from `get(Key key)` and a no-op for all other overridden methods.

Comment: I tried `DiskCacheAdapter` that is like your `NoOpDiskCache`. It'll stop showing/loading all image.

Comment: strange, I was able to confirm on their samples (imgur) that setting a no-op disk cache works (loading took some time though). Also a simpler approach I realize is to set the cache to null which internally uses the `DiskCacheAdapter` which is a no-op